# Wild card in java Generic and <? super T> meaning, lower or upper bound

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends, bounded-wildcard

So I am reading about generic method and I am get confused. Let me state the problem here first:

In this example: Suppose that I need a version of selectionSort that works for any type T, by using an external comparable supplied by the caller.

First attempt:

```
public static <T> void selectionSort(T[] arr, Comparator<T> myComparator){....}
```

Suppose that I have:

- Defined vehicle class
- created VehicleComparator implementing Comparator while
  compare vehicles by their price.
- created Truck extends vehicle
- instantiated Truck[] arr ; VehicleComparator myComparator

Now, I do:

```
selectionSort(arr, myComparator);
```

and it won't work, because myComparator is not available for any subclass of Vehicle.

Then, I do this:

```
public static <T> void selectionSort(T[] arr, Comparator<? super T> myComparator){....}
```

This declaration will work, but I don't completely sure what I've been doing... I know use  is the way to go. If "? super T" means "an unknown supertype of T", then am I imposing a upper or lower bound? Why is it super? My intention is to let any subclass of T to use myComparator, why "? super T". So confused... I'd appreciate if you have any insight in this..

Thanks ahead!

Comment: This would help you. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/

Comment: This should be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: This also might help you.  **Effective Java** book suggests to remember this - **PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`)**.  Use `extends` for producing classes, and use `super` for consumer classes.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar thanks a lot! The blog is ready good and it even have a example in it!

Comment: "and it won't work, because myComparator is not available for any subclass of Vehicle." This is false. `myComparator` compares `Vehicle`, yes. And `Truck[]` is a `Vehicle[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you could have solved it by having `Vehicle[]` which you then added `Truck`s to.

The reason you need `<? super T>` goes back to the generics rule that `Comparator<Truck>` is not a subtype of `Comparator<Vehicle>`; the unbounded type `T` must match exactly, which it doesn't.

In order for a suitable `Comparator` to be passed in, it must be a `Comparator` of the class being compared or any super class of it, because in OO languages any class may be treated as an instance of a superclass. Thus, it doesn't matter what the generic type of the `Comparator` is, as long as it's a supertype of the array's component type.

Comment: but who said `T` was `Truck`? If you choose `T` to be `Vehicle`, then it works.

Comment: @newacct if you read the wuestion carefully, you'll see that he instantiated `Truck[] arr`, then passed that in to `T[]`, so java inferred `T` as `Truck`. There's no doubt about it.

Comment: Sure, his compiler may have inferred it that way. But if the inference is insufficient he can always manually provide the type argument. You said "you *need* `<? super T>`" which is not true since it can work without it.

Answer (score 4):

The quizzical phrase `? super T` means that the destination list may have elements of any type
that is a supertype of `T`, just as the source list may have elements of any type that is a
subtype of `T`.

We can see pretty simple example `copy` from `Collections`:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
   for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    dst.set(i, src.get(i));
   }
}
```

And call:

```
List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(2, 3.14, "four");
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
Collections.copy(objs, ints);
assert objs.toString().equals("[5, 6, four]");
```

As with any generic method, the type parameter may be inferred or may be given explicitly. In this case, there are four possible choices, all of which type-check and all of which have the same effect:

```
Collections.copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Object>copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Number>copy(objs, ints);
Collections.<Integer>copy(objs, ints);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.. So "? super T" could be either a upper bound or a lower bound, depending on where  I put this phrase, right?

Comment: The `super` is a lower bound, when  `extends` is an upper bound

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature

```
public static <T> void selectionSort(T[] arr, Comparator<? super T> myComparator)
```

means that if you invoke it with an array of type `T` than you must also provide a `Comparator` of type T or a super type of `T`.

For example if you have the following classes

```
class Vehicle {}

class Truck extends Vehicle {}

class BigTruck extends Truck {}

class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<Vehicle> {    
    public int compare(Vehicle o1, Vehicle o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class BigTruckComparator implements Comparator<BigTruck> {
    public int compare(BigTruck o1, BigTruck o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class TruckComparator implements Comparator<Truck> {
    public int compare(Truck o1, Truck o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

then this will work

```
Truck[] trucks = ...;
selectionSort(trucks, new TruckComparator());
selectionSort(trucks, new VehicleComparator());
```

Because

- `TruckComparator` implements `Comparator<Truck>` and a `Truck` is equal to the array's type `Truck`
- `VehicleComparator` implements `Comparator<Vehicle>`  and a `Vehicle` is a super type of the array's type `Truck`

This will **NOT WORK**

```
selectionSort(trucks, new BigTruckComparator());
```

Because a `BigTruckComparator` is a `Comparator<BigTruck>` and a `BigTruck` is not a super type of the array's type `Truck`.

Answer (score 1):

The two signatures are equivalent in terms of power -- for any set of arguments, if there exists a choice of type arguments that works for one of them, there exists a choice of type arguments that works for the other one, and vice versa.

You are simply running into limited inference in your compiler. Simply explicitly specify the desired type argument:

```
YourClass.<Vehicle>selectionSort(arr, myComparator);
```

Comment: +1 Though it may be worth mentioning that this is only true because arrays are covariant (`Truck[]` is a `Vehicle[]`). If the method took a `List<T>` instead, `Comparator<? super T>` would be needed.